# Draw connection line between some coupled data points by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, connect

In my correlation ggplot, I would like to add some extra "mini-regression lines" between some pairs of data points.

I have 10 species, which were observed twice (in 2010 and in 2014).

```
set.seed(42)
obs_2010 <- runif(10, min=1, max=20)
obs_2014 <- runif(10, min=1, max=20)
species <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","L")
DF <- data.frame(species, obs_2010, obs_2014, stringsAsFactors=T)
```

I plotted the 2010 values vs the 2014 values, and I got a correlation plot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8fM3.jpg

Some of these species are sister species (let's say A-L, B-I, G-H). 
In addition to the regression line based on all 10 species, I would like to draw a line between points A and L, another line between B and I, another between G and H. 
Basically, I would like to get this plot (now made with Paint ;) )
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uXEQ.png

Here some unsuccesfull trials I made:

```
#pairs to connect: A-L, B-I, G-H
sister=c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,3,2,1)

sistasp <- data.frame(species=DF$species,sister=sister, stringsAsFactors=T)

#trial1
ggplot(DF, aes(x=obs_2010, y=obs_2014)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=species), shape=16, size=3) + theme_bw() + xlim(0,20) + ylim(0,20) +
  geom_smooth(method=glm, se=F, col="black") +   
  geom_line(aes(group=sister), na.rm=T)
#almost good, but also points with NA (those without sister species) are connected

#trial2
ggplot(DF, aes(x=obs_2010, y=obs_2014)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=species), shape=16, size=3) + theme_bw() + xlim(0,20) + ylim(0,20) +
  geom_smooth(method=glm, se=F, col="black") +  
  geom_segment(data = merge(DF, sistasp, by = "sister"), 
             aes(x=y2010.x, xend=y2010.y, y=y2014.x, yend=y2014.y))
#error message Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y2010.x' not found
```

Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 0):

So I think your first method was almost correct, but you might want to subset the data you're passing to `geom_line()` to just the data that has sister information. I added `$sister` to `DF` so that the grouping is in line with the data.

```
DF$sister <- sister

ggplot(DF, aes(x=obs_2010, y=obs_2014)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=species), shape=16, size=3) + theme_bw() + xlim(0,20) + ylim(0,20) +
  geom_smooth(method=glm, se=F, col="black") +   
  geom_line(data = DF[!is.na(sister),], aes(group=sister), na.rm=T)
```

Is that giving you what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you! =) It gives the desired plot for the example dataframe. But for some reason it does not work with my actual dataframe =(

Comment: Any ideas what went wrong or what errors are being thrown?

Comment: The problem may be linked to the order of factor levels. It connects correctly only two pairs, then it connects species that are not supposed to be paired and some NA's together.

Comment: If you know the start- and end-coordinates a priori, you could also try with `geom_segment()`, which don't forces lines to be ordered along the x-axis.